# I want to integrate oauth code grant flow for and spa and back end is hosted on azure functions

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, single-page-application

I am working on an SPA in angular and azure functions as back end. and using Azure active directory for single sign on. I have implemented Implicit Flow and it works fine. but the issue is that I do not want to expose the `access_token` in the browser.

I want to implement code grant flow with `PKCE` validation. I need recommendations how to do it properly in azure functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that the implict flow is working fine but as per the new [guidelines](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/) it is not recommending.

To use PKCE flow, we can make a http post call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/outh2/authorize endpoint by passing **code_challenge** along with other parameters (client_id=b2bc09xxx-xxxxx, response_type=code, redirect_uri= http://localhost, response_mode=query, resource='https://graph.microsoft.com/', state=1234, code_challenge_method= S256, code_challenge={authPKCEChallenge}) in the body and gets the authorization code.

And use that authorization code and make a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/outh2/token endpoint by passing **code_verifier** along with other parameters (grant_type='authorization_code', client_id='b2bc09xxx-xxxxx', code:'_accessCode', redirect_uri='http://localhost', resource='https://graph.microsoft.com/', code_verfifier={authPKCEVerifier}) in the body and gets the token.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as code is used once to generate a  token. How can I save a token on server for a user due to stateless nature of SPA and Azure functions. How can I identify a token that belongs to a user. There is not a much help around on the internet on the topic.